# Unable to rename files in python using OS module

Tags: python-3.x

My Script:

```
import os

cwd = os.getcwd()
ff = os.listdir()
for x in os.listdir():
    if x.endswith(".txt"):
        for i in range(len(ff)):
            os.rename(x, f"{i}.txt")
```

Explanation: I tried to rename all text files in a directory using a for loop from 1.txt to n.txt
but getting the following error though the file is present and path is also correct.

Comment: Your code is incorrect. First iteration of nested `for i in range(len(ff))` loop renames file `x` which then does not exist for second and further iterations.

Answer (score 0):

*What do you use the nested `for loop` for?*

The main loop is already going through all the files.

If you want to rename all the text files in the directory with serial numbers, just use index indicator in the first loop and remove the nesting.

You can create an `idx` counter, for example:

```py
import os

idx = 1
for x in os.listdir():
    if x.endswith(".txt"):
        os.rename(x, f"{idx}.txt")
        idx += 1
```